# Convert string to time in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In my excel sheet I have a column with time. But the time is given in the following format.

```
1m 10.37s
2m 8.42s
```

I want to convert this to hh:mm:ss

Just can't figure out how.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do these minutes ever exceed 60? Are there always two trailing decimals after the seconds? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: No, min are always 60s. And there aren't always two trailing decimals after the second. I've tried TRIM with left and right etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=--("0:"&SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1),"m ",":"))
```

Obviously cells have been numberformatted `hh:mm:ss`.

---

Edit:

```
=TIME(0,IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND("m",A1)-1),0),-LOOKUP(1,-MID(A1,FIND(" "," "&A1),ROW($1:$99))))
```

Comment: Oh, one more little issue I do have times which aren't a min. for example 58.80s

Comment: @GreenSquirrel, see the edit.